# Can not get eBay auth Token to work

Tags: php, xml, ebay-api

I am making an ecom website for a class, and I am trying to tie it all into my eBay account. Really not a fan of eBay's API. I am using their test tool:

header:

```
X-EBAY-API-SITEID:0
X-EBAY-API-COMPATIBILITY-LEVEL:967
X-EBAY-API-CALL-NAME:GetSellerList
X-EBAY-API-DEV-NAME:.........
X-EBAY-API-APP-NAME:........
X-EBAY-API-CERT-NAME:.........
```

and request code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetSellerListRequest xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <RequesterCredentials>
    <eBayAuthToken>[I enter my 872 char auth key here...]</eBayAuthToken>
  </RequesterCredentials>
    <ErrorLanguage>en_US</ErrorLanguage>
    <WarningLevel>High</WarningLevel>
     <!--You can use DetailLevel or GranularityLevel in a request, but not both-->
  <GranularityLevel>Fine</GranularityLevel> 
     <!-- Enter a valid Time range to get the Items listed using this format
          2013-03-21T06:38:48.420Z -->
  <StartTimeFrom>2016-03-21T06:38:48.420Z</StartTimeFrom> 
  <StartTimeTo>2016-08-01T06:38:48.420Z</StartTimeTo> 
  <IncludeWatchCount>true</IncludeWatchCount> 
  <Pagination> 
    <EntriesPerPage>200</EntriesPerPage> 
  </Pagination> 
</GetSellerListRequest>
```

and my response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GetSellerListResponse 
  xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
  <Timestamp>2016-08-02T03:21:44.330Z</Timestamp>
  <Ack>Failure</Ack>
  <Errors>
    <ShortMessage>Auth token is invalid.</ShortMessage>
    <LongMessage>Validation of the authentication token in API request failed.</LongMessage>
    <ErrorCode>931</ErrorCode>
    <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
    <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
  </Errors>
  <Version>967</Version>
  <Build>E967_CORE_APISELLING_17965876_R1</Build>
</GetSellerListResponse>
```

What am I doing wrong?

In the test tool I have production selected and am using a production auth key.....

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to do this from scratch. Thousands have already integrated into eBay using PHP. There's plenty of ready made SDKs that simplify and have built in error handling. Here's a popular one that's currently maintained.

https://github.com/davidtsadler/ebay-sdk-php